# elements have been added to a list but using it outside the method return an empty list "Flutter"

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a private list _barbershops, i used it inside the methode **getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase()**, i added to it some elements from firestore when i print its value in the end of the method i can see elements that are instences of that list's type... meaning it is full and firestore did its part with no error.
However trying to print it outside of the methode (with its getter) it returns an empty list

> here is my code file:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:hafefly/models/babershopModel.dart';

class BarbershopService {
  FirebaseFirestore? _instance;
  List<Barbershop> _barbershops = [];

  List<Barbershop> getBarbershops() {
    print(_barbershops);
    return _barbershops;
  }

  Future<void> getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase() async {
    _instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    CollectionReference barbershopsCollection =
        _instance!.collection('barbershops');

    QuerySnapshot barbershops = await barbershopsCollection.get();
    for (var element in barbershops.docs) {
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
          await barbershopsCollection.doc(element.id).get();
      var data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      Barbershop barb = Barbershop(
          name: data['name'],
          rating: data['rating'],
          vip: data['vip'],
          location: data['location'],
          latitude: data['latitude'],
          longitude: data['longitude'],
          open: data['open'],
          close: data['close']);
      _barbershops.add(barb);
      print(_barbershops);
    }
  }
}
```

> Console log for the print inside the method:

```
I/flutter ( 6864): [Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop', Instance of 'Barbershop']
```

> Console log for the print inside the getter:
> `I/flutter ( 6864): []`

Comment: Your response is an array, not a map. loop in 'data'

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling `getBarbershops()` *after* `getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase()` *completes*?  You don't show where you're calling each function.  Most likely you're calling `getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase()` and not waiting for it to complete before calling `getBarbershops()`.

Comment: I am calling them in home.dart to use the list as a data for a widget, ` BarbershopService barbsp = Provider.of<BarbershopService>(context, listen: false); BarbershopService().getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase(); List<Barbershop> barbershops = BarbershopService().getBarbershops(); ` I also tried calling getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase() in getBarbershops() as follows: ` List<Barbershop> getBarbershops() { getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase(); print(_barbershops); return _barbershops; } ` but no luck @jamesdlin

Comment: can you explain more please ? @BenjithKizhisseri

Comment: You're calling `BarbershopService().getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase(); List<Barbershop> barbershops = BarbershopService().getBarbershops();`.  The `getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase()` method returns a `Future`; it is asynchronous, and you must wait for it to complete first if you expect `getBarbershops()` to return the filled `List`.  Do: `await BarbershopService().getBarbershopCollectionFromFirebase(); List<Barbershop> barbershops = BarbershopService().getBarbershops();`.  Also see [What is a Future, and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63017280/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

1. I called `getBarbershopFromFirebase()` inside the `getBarbershops()` method
2. in the `home.dart` (where I wanted to use the widget based on this data) I fetched the data using this method:

   ```
   _fetchListItems() async {
    List<Barbershop>? barbershopsList =
        await BarbershopService().getBarbershops();

    setState(() {
      for (var item in barbershopsList) {
        _barbershops.add(item);
      }
    });

    return _barbershops;
   }
   ```
3. I called the `_fetchListItems()` inside the `initState()`
4. I initialised a `Future<List<Barbershops>> barbershops`
5. I used a `FutureBuilder()` with a `future: barbershops`
6. with the help of `ListView.builder` I put `itemCount: _barbershops.length`
7. in the `itemBuilder(context, index)` I replaced the hard coded data with `_barbershops[index]`

I hope I helped someone with my journey experience.